# ISNULL(Column1,Column2) equivalent in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get something equivalent to `ISNULL` in Microsoft Access.

I have the `NZ` function, but I'm not sure how to make it accept a Column name.

```
SELECT[BANK],[AMOUNT] FROM[BANKDETAILS] WHERE [BANK] = NZ('SBI', BANK]) AND[CITY]=NZ('Delhi', CITY) AND[IFSC]=NZ(4363,IFSC)
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. A quick web search indicates that Access does have a `isnull` function. Please take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question, then [edit] your question accordingly. What happens when you run your query? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: @Robert: MS Access `ISNULL` is different than SQL Server `ISNULL`. The Access equivalent is the aforementioned `NZ`. `ISNULL` in Access takes a single argument and returns a Boolean result depending on whether the argument value is null or not.

Comment: NZ didn't work as I was trying to use it throufg ASP.NET. IIF(ISNULL(originalvalue),argumentifnull,originalvalue)  did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like you would `IsNull`. You're currently reversing the arguments.

The first argument is the column that could be null, the second is the value if it is null:

```
SELECT [BANK],[AMOUNT] FROM [BANKDETAILS] WHERE [BANK] = NZ([BANK],'SBI') AND[CITY]=NZ(CITY, 'Delhi') AND [IFSC]=NZ(IFSC, 4363)
```

Do note that comparing columns to themselves is silly, and an ineffective way to test if they're not null. The `Nz` here has no value.

Comment: Actually I am using ASP.NET which is tking these values from var, I just posted it that way to avoid complications. I guess I found the issue. The column name in access should be in [] to be recognised, that's all I missed.